# xml xsl recombine values

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm real newbee to XML/XSL and try to convert a XML into another XML format.
I have a filemaker export which I have to convert. The XML looks like that

```
<machineName>
        <DATA>Machine 1</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 2</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 3</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 4</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 5</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 6</DATA>
        <DATA>Machine 7</DATA>
    </machineName>
    <machineType>
        <DATA>12</DATA>
        <DATA>15</DATA>
        <DATA>31</DATA>
        <DATA>44</DATA>
        <DATA>14</DATA>
        <DATA>12</DATA>
        <DATA>54</DATA>
    </machineType>
    <machineBuilt>
        <DATA>1982</DATA>
        <DATA>1985</DATA>
        <DATA>1977</DATA>
        <DATA>1966</DATA>
        <DATA>1999</DATA>
        <DATA>1975</DATA>
        <DATA>2001</DATA>
    </machineBuilt>
```

And that is how it should look like in the end:

```
 <machine>
        <name>Machine 1</name>
        <machineType>12</machineType>
        <machineBuilt>1982</machineBuilt>
 </machine>
 <machine>
        <name>Machine 2</name>
        <machineType>15</machineType>
        <machineBuilt>1985</machineBuilt>
 </machine>
 <machine>
        <name>Machine 3</name>
        <machineType>31</machineType>
        <machineBuilt>1977</machineBuilt>
 </machine>
 .... and so on
```

I managed to read the "machineName/Data" values and convert them to the desired formats with the xsl:for-each command. But I don't know how to read the others values within the loop.

Can anybody give me a clue?

thx for your help
dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to "transposition" problems like this is to pick one of the first level items, then iterate over its second level children and create one output "row" for each of those, containing the data from corresponding positions in all the input rows.  Assuming the current context is the common parent element of `machineName`, `machineType` and `machineBuilt`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="machineName/DATA">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  <machine>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
    <type><xsl:value-of select="../../machineType/DATA[$pos]"/></type>
    <built><xsl:value-of select="../../machineBuilt/DATA[$pos]"/></built>
  </machine>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You may find it slightly more readable to store the three parallel sets of DATA elements in separate variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="machineName" select="machineName/DATA" />
<xsl:variable name="machineType" select="machineType/DATA" />
<xsl:variable name="machineBuilt" select="machineBuilt/DATA" />
<xsl:for-each select="$machineName">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  <machine>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="$machineName[$pos]"/></name>
    <type><xsl:value-of select="$machineType[$pos]"/></type>
    <built><xsl:value-of select="$machineBuilt[$pos]"/></built>
  </machine>
</xsl:for-each>
```